# Does AVA have a default for timeouts?

Tags: javascript, ava

The documentation mentions the ability to configure a timeout, but it neglects to mention the default state. I'll try and look at the source code to figure this out to post a helpful answer here shortly.

https://github.com/avajs/ava

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the CLI argument `--timeout` is not supplied then the default is set to `conf.timeout`, which is extracted via an `ava.config.js` file (optional). So AVA does NOT have a default timeout without a user explicitly setting it.

https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/lib/cli.js

https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/lib/load-config.js

Comment: Interestingly this came up in our Spectrum chat recently: https://spectrum.chat/ava/general/is-there-any-default-global-timeout-for-tests-in-ava-nothing-found-in-docs~39300859-6795-4e56-8326-224719d72078 — It'd be good to have that added to our documentation. Perhaps you're interested in raising a PR?

Comment: Sure. I can take a look and make a suggestion.

Comment: I appreciate feedback. If my answer was accurate please upvote.

Answer (score 2):

The original answer still is informative. However, it appears like there is a [default timeout of 10s now](https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/docs/07-test-timeouts.md) according to a a markdown file on AVA's github repo.